# SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (in R/Shiny)

Tags: r, ssl, shiny

In a R/shiny project, I have to bring data from endpoint and often use RCurl to do it.
But in this case, the console prints a error about local certificate.

```
library(RCurl)
data = getURL("https://corporatewebsite.kl/ProyectosTD/getData/dfs32b98565sd65dfkjswfr8J")
```

> Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

[image: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate]

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some test. For example, using Mac computer this problem does not appear, however in shinyapps.io it does.
The problem is that RCurl doesn't get the certificate from the website, then we need to add this certificate like a parameter.

In order to get the certificate you need to follow this steps:

Open the broswer (I used firefox), then go to endpoint (or API) URL and click on the padlock icon.

[Broswer + click on padlock icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIQ6H.png)

Then choose "More information" option, and you will find a button called "View Certificate" in the window that pops up, then click it!

[Button Called "View Certificate" in website indetify window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opbAI.png)

In the new tab will open on your browser there is a section called "Miscellaneous" where you will find the links to download the pem files. Download them!

[Miscellaneousd and links of pem files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2V5x.png)

Finally, add this files in your R project "Working directory" and add one of them like a parameter into getURL command (it is one of two).

```
library(RCurl)
data =getURL("https://corporatewebsite.kl/ProyectosTD/getData/dfs32b98565sd65dfkjswfr8J", cainfo="file.pem")
```